# Сортировка многомерного массива по внутренним значениям String - PHP

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив вида:

```
    $arr = array (
    [0] => array (
           [0] => 'BString',
           [1] => array(....)),
    [1] => array (
           [0] => 'AString',
           [1] => array(....)),
    [2] => array (
           [0] => 'CString',
           [1] => array(....)), 
... );
```

Нужно отсортировать массив по (x)Strig по алфавиту, то есть, чтобы получилось:

```
$arr = array (
    [0] => array (
           [0] => 'AString',
           [1] => array(....)),
    [1] => array (
           [0] => 'BString',
           [1] => array(....)),
    [2] => array (
           [0] => 'CString',
           [1] => array(....)), 
... );
```

Comment: Замечательно. Теперь гуглите `php sort arrays` и изучаете результаты.

Comment: @u_mulder, второй день пытаюсь вникнуть. не выходит. если не сложно, помогите разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Вас интересуют [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php), чей порядок сортировки **определяется пользователем**:

Используйте `usort` c кастомным колбеком:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    // $a и $b это пара сравниваемых элементов вашего массива
    // вам требуется сравнить значение с ключом [0] элемента $a
    // со значением с ключом [0] элемента $b
    // так как оба значения ($a[0] и $b[0]) - строки, 
    // можно использовать функцию `strcmp`
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
```

В общем-то это всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($arr, function($one, $two) {
    return strnatcasecmp($one[0], $two[0]);
});
```

Функция сортирует по алгоритму `Natural Order String Comparison`.